# How to start multiple tornado instance using bash

Tags: python, bash, port, tornado

I have a tornado server and I would like to start multiple instances on different ports, so I created the following bash file to start 3 instances.

```
#!/bin/bash

#start tornado instances in different ports
python startup.py --port="8081"
python startup.py --port="8082"
python startup.py --port="8083"
```

As you can see, the above code is problematic, because the first command will block the second one.
So anyone has any idea about how to start 3 together?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run in the background using `&` and `nohup`.

Comment: Tried, the 8082 one still not working

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). u can start the commands in background running as a daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run them just in current session, add `&` at the end of each line:

```
python startup.py --port="8081" &
python startup.py --port="8082" &
python startup.py --port="8083" &
```

But it is much more convenient to use `systemd`, `upstart` or other init system, because it gives you an easy way to `start`, `stop` and `restart` your instances.

If you need an example, i will update this answer.

---

#### Update

As long as you're using OS X, you can use default init system – `launchd`.

**Step 1** – create a config file for your job:

```
vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_job.plist
```

File contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>my.awesome.label</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
                <string>/Users/ivanvinogradov/tort.py</string>
        </array>

        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>

        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>ivanvinogradov</string>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>60</integer>

        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/AlTest1.err</string>

        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/AlTest1.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Path to your `.py` script goes to `<key>ProgramArguments</key>`.
Put name of user, who will run your job in `<key>UserName</key>` section.
Also note that `<key>Label</key>` section is required.

**Step 2** – ensure that `.plist` file has appropriate permissions:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_job.plist
sudo chmod 600 /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_job.plist
```

**Step 3** – start and stop your job:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_job.plist
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_job.plist
```

This is a very simple example of `launchd`. You can learn more about it here on SO or on an [Apple doc page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Comment: Yeah, please give me an example, I am on macOS, and maybe also how to run it in background as a daemon. thank you.

Comment: updated an answer, take a look

Comment: Ok, that's a little bit complicate, I guess I will just use &, thank you very much